# get data from gridview without querying database

Tags: gridview, select

I am new at this so please bear with me...

I have managed to get the following code to work...so when I click on the "select" link in each row of the gridview, the data is transfered to other label/textbox on the webpage.

So far so good, the thing is that everytime I click on **select**...it goes and checks on the database for the data and there is a delay of a few seconds...
I was hoping that the data, since it is already visible on the gridrows, is simply "picked up" and used on other labels/textboxes...without requerying the database.

Is this possible ?
Thanks in advance

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells(8).Text
    Label2.Text = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells(9).Text
    TextBox1.Text = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells(7).Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you databinding on every postback?  That would be one cause of the requerying.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean...sorry, as I said, I am new at this  :)
What do you mean ? How do I stop it from databinding on every postback?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this code at the point where you're binding to your grid.

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Grid.DataBind()
End If
```

This way you will only bind the grid once when the page first loads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my apologies, but I am not sure where I have to put the code you mention...could you give me a hint ?

Comment: Hi, this is the code I put on my page.
I get no errors, so it's ok, however still doing postback when "select" link is clicked.

Anything else missing ? Thanks for your response

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     If Not IsPostBack Then
      Gridview2.DataBind()
  End If     
    End Sub